# Doctrine Resolve_target_entity in config

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I found this on the doctrine website page:
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/resolve-target-entity-listener.html

A way to let my entity communicate with an interface which then can be configurable. The only problem is that i cant find anywhere how to put it in my array config. I already checked the configuration source but there is nothing in the docs:
https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule/blob/master/docs/configuration.md

Hope someone can help

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use it like this:

```php
'doctrine' => array(
    'entity_resolver' => array(
        'orm_default' => array(
            'resolvers' => array(
                'MyModule\Entity\FooInterface' => 'OtherModule\Entity\Foo',
            ),
        ),
    ),
```

We use it e.g. here (as a live example) in [Soflomo\Blog](https://github.com/Soflomo/Blog/blob/master/config/module.config.php#L356-L364).

Comment: Works like a charm but is there also a way to define on which columns to join etc?

Comment: Yes, you should do that in the mapping. Note I am using the interface here, the entity resolver listener replaces this with the "real" entity: https://github.com/Soflomo/Blog/blob/master/config/mapping/Soflomo.Blog.Entity.AbstractArticle.dcm.xml#L13-L15

Comment: I see that but isnt there a way to do this with the meta info as docblock code? The thing is i am using this everywhere else etc. Its a bit strange to switch with some parts to xml

Comment: The XML and YAML are replaceable. We just use XML, if you use YAML, you also have relational annotations for that. Just make sure you reference the interface in your YAML and not the instance. Besides that, it is just the same.

Comment: Ok but there is no way to do that on a annotation based way?

Comment: Dirkos, please read my answer. 1) mappings in Doctrine are possible via XML, YAML or annotations. 2) relations between entities are called associations and part of the mapping (so, associations are defined also either in XML, YAML or annotations. 3) the entity resolver listener is a Doctrine configuration thing and independent of the mapping. Therefore it cannot be part of the XML, YAML or annotations. The config of the entity target listener should be defined as written above. All mappings (**including** associations) are in the format you like the most (again, XML, YAML or annotations).